# Why does TV presenter say "It is a friendly dinosaur, too" when there is only one dinosaur in the studio?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, too-also

This is from a TV show [Ellen's guest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bi2NgISjcgI) (see 1:40-1:42)

The guest is fond of dinosaurs . So, to surprise him, they bring a dinosaur into the studio. But before the presenter brings the dinosaur in, she says to him:

**"It is a friendly dinosaur, too."**

I could not understand why she said **"......, too".** which gives the impression that there is another dinosaur in the studio. Because the **"too"** is referring to the **"IT",** then **"......., too."** seems to be nonsense.

Then I thought about what **"too"** might be referring to. I came to conclusion that it might be referring to the feature of the dinosaur, rather than the dinosaur itself **(IT)**. In other words, it is referring to the **"dinosaur's being friendly"** rather than the **"IT"**.

If what I am thinking is true, then the **"too"** creates a meaning like: **"In addition to many other features (of it), the dinosaur has another feature, and that feature is to be friendly."**

Am I right in my thinking?

Comment: In addition to **being a dinosaur**, it is also friendly. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your thinking. The presenter first says that a dinosaur is 'here today'. Then she adds the additional information that it (the dinosaur) is friendly.

> Too (adverb)
>
> in addition; also.
>
> *"is he coming too?"*

(Oxford Languages)

Comment: My new girlfriend is beautiful, intelligent, and kind. She owns a brewery too.